# $\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2e^{-x/y}}y\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've come across a rather difficult expression to integrate.
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2e^{-x/y}}y\,dx$$
Is there an easy way to solve this? I've solved it manually which involved multiple u-subs and integration by parts, and took up a decent amount of my time. This comes from a probability textbook so I doubt they want me to spend so much time solving an integral.

The final answer should be $2y^2$.

Comment: The book probably assume you know the identity $\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t} dt = n!$. This integral representation of $n!$ is useful when you want to transform series which contains $n!$ in its numerator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let us define $z = x/y$, so $dz=dx/y$. Hence, we need to compute the following integration:
$$y^2 \int_0^{\infty} z^2 e^{-z} dz = y^2 \Gamma(3)=2y^2.$$

The definition of the $\Gamma$ function:
$$\Gamma (n) = \int_0^{\infty} z^{n-1} e^{-z} dz,$$
and
$$\Gamma (n) = (n-1) \Gamma(n-1)=(n-1)!.$$

Comment: I guess I have to become more used to recognizing when the gamma function is appropriate, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Since $y$ is constant, a change of variables $u = x/y$ means that you just need to compute
$$y^2 \int_0^{\infty} u^2 e^{-u}\, du$$
which is handled by two applications of integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

Using a probabilistic approach denote $X\sim \mathcal{E}xp (1/y)$, hence
$$
Var(X) = \mathbb{E}X^2 - \mathbb{E}^2X = y^2, 
$$
hence, 
$$
\mathbb{E}X^2 = \int_0^{\infty}x^2\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}dx=Var(X)+\mathbb{E}^2X=y^2+y^2=2y^2.
$$
Basically, without probability you can just use integration by parts by denoting $u'_x = \frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}$ and $v=x^2$.